# fadeOut fired just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jquery to display an error div, which is defined as:

```
<div id="Div1" style="color: Black; background-color:Orange; font: bold small 'trebuchet ms',helvetica,sans-serif;"></div>
```

Within the error method I call the Error Div as follows:

```
$("#Div1").html('');
$("#Div1").html('Failed to upload. Please try again.').fadeOut(2000, function () { $(this).remove(); });
```

Problem is that the error div gets called just once. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by 'gets called just once'? What would you want it to do?

Comment: its getting called only the first time I get an error.. not subsequently.

Comment: That's because you're removing the element after fading out. See answers :)

Comment: @Armatus. This is happening after commenting the remove code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in fadeOut function:

```
$("#Div1").html('');
$("#Div1").html('Failed to upload. Please try again.')
 .fadeOut(2000, function () { $(this).html('').show(); });
});
```

Comment: I checked in FF\Chromium and Opera it works fine. I edited the answer to show the full code.

Comment: I tried this code...  `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function PopUp() {
            $("#Div1").html('');
            $("#Div1").html('Failed to upload. Please try again.').fadeOut(2000, function () { $(this).html('').show(); });
        return false;}
    </script>   <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="txt" OnClientClick="return PopUp();" />`

Comment: Ok, Delete OnClientClick from <Button> and add code: $('#btn').click(function(){
    $("#Div1").html('');
    $("#Div1").html('Failed to upload. Please try again.')
     .fadeOut(2000, function () { $(this).html('').show(); });
  });

Comment: Actually this is performing the `PostBack`. Why should I use Client Side code to Perform `PostBack` in this situation ?

Comment: Java script is executed on the client side. So I think the difference is not present, if I understood your asp code.

Comment: I meant, Button is doing the `Postback` after removing `OnClientClick`. That's why it was preventing the `PostBack` by using return type and in this way it shows just one time.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use .text instead of .html, try this:

```
$("#Div1").text('Failed to upload. Please try again.').fadeOut(2000, function () {
    $(this).text('').show(); 
});
```

As .html() is meant to add html content. From the jquery manual:

> .html( htmlString )
>
> htmlStringA string of HTML to set as the content of each matched element.

See: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Comment: Try this (you have to show the div, because fadeOut hides it)

Answer (score 0):

try this

here is an update

```
$("#Div1").html('Failed to upload. Please try again.').fadeOut(2000, function () {
        $(this).html('').show(); 
});
```

Comment: doesn't work. The error is displayed just once (the first time)